# die() method in an snake game for poisonous food

Tags: java, android, game-engine

I am new to Andoid and I have a simple snake game. 
And i have a poisoned apple(Only one which is generated at a random place on the screen) if the snake eats it  dies.

Any suggestions?

My PoisonedFood class:

```
public abstract class PoisonedFood {
    public abstract float getX();

    public abstract float getY();

    public abstract void eatPoison();

    public abstract void render(GL10 gl);

}
```

My SFood class:

```
public class SFood extends PoisonedFood {
    public static final float RADIUS = .07f;

    private float x, y, angle, speed;

    public SFood(float x, float y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void render(GL10 gl) {
        Image.setRotation((System.currentTimeMillis() / 6) % 360);
        Image.setScale(RADIUS, RADIUS);
        SGame.fImage.draw(gl, x, y);
    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }


    public void eatPoison() {
        //The method
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any real question here. What is it that you want to know?

Comment: And what makes you think random people who know nothing about your app have any better ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Emm I guess **snake** should eat food, not food should eat something.

```
public class Snake() {
  public void eatFood(SFood food) {
    //check if food is poisoned
    if (food instanceof PoisonedFood) {
      this.die();
    }

    //or if you are hater of instanceof or you have isPoisoned() method
    if (food.isPoisoned()) {
      this.die();
    }
  }

  public void die() {
      //snake dies here
  }
}
```

And `snake.eatFood()` for sure should run by *collision* event of food and snake.

Comment: I'd probably make SFood have an `isPoisonous` method. There doesn't appear to be the need for a new class for that

Comment: @cricket_007 was about to say the same thing. In most cases instanceof checks indicated bad design.

Comment: @cricket_007 updated. Just didnt see any isPoisoned() method so adviced shortest option.

Comment: @DEADMC yeah well, you redesigned enough other structure of the OP's program, that you may as well do this too. The OP's PoisonedFood class has getX, getY, and eat...

Comment: Also, using the OP's class structure would make instanceof not work, as he's defined all food as poisoned food